# Need a real VBA equivalent for Excel Value function

Tags: vba, excel

As mentioned in the title, I need a VBA equivalent to the Excel Value function.  My data set looks like this: [Data set example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9APR.png)

What I am looking for is VBA code equivalent to this:  `=Value(A2)+Value(B2)`.  That would go in column C

The output must be the same as that function.  For the given example, column C should end up looking like this: [End product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L1cG.png)

More than that, it needs to only have the value in the cell after the macro is run, rather than displaying the value and still having that formula in it.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
   strValue = Val(sht.Range("A" & i))
   strValue1 = Val(sht.Range("B" & i))
   sht.Range("C" & i).Value = strValue + strValue1
Next i
```

I also tried variations on this, a couple of which are shown below:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
   strValue = Evaluate(sht.Range("A" & i))
   strValue1 = Evaluate(sht.Range("B" & i))
   sht.Range("C" & i).Value = strValue + strValue1
Next i

For i = 1 To LastRow
   strValue = sht.Range("A" & i)
   strValue1 = sht.Range("B" & i)
   strVal = Evaluate(strValue)
   strVal1 = Evaluate(strValue1)
   sht.Range("C" & i).Value = strVal + strVal1
Next i
```

I can't find anything that will work for me.  The output in C for the example set ends up being just 9.  Pretty sure it is taking the first number in A and adding it to the first number in B.  So when the hour in B changes to 1 C displays 10.

I also tried simply:

```
For i=1 To LastRow
   sht.Range("C" & i).Value = sht.Range("A" & i).Value + sht.Range("B" & i).Value
Next i
```

That just concatenated the text to the format `9/03/15 00:00:00`

Any and all help appreciated.  Bonus if you can point me in the right direction for changing the final C values from that number (ie. 42250.00017) to the custom date/time format `'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'`.

Edit:  Here is my code up to the sticking point.  Everything else works as I want it to, the only problem is with the last `For` loop.

```
Sub sbOrganizeData()

Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim sFound As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCSV As String
Dim strValue As Double
Dim strValue1 As Double
Dim strVal As Long
Dim strVal1 As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("all016").Delete
Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set sheet = Sheets.Add
Set Sheet2 = Sheets.Add
sheet.Name = "all016"
Sheet2.Name = "Sheet1"

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.Path
strCSV = "*.csv"
sFound = Dir(strFile & "\*.csv")
If sFound <> "" Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFile & "\" & sFound
End If
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("solar.xlsm").Sheets("all016").Range("A1")
Workbooks(sFound).Close

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("all016")
LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

sht.Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert

For i = 1 To LastRow
   'Code that doesn't quite work here'

   sht.Range("C" & i).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
Next i
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Application.WorksheetFunction.Value`?

Comment: Try this `strValue = Evaluate("--" & sht.Range("A" & i).Address(1,1,,1))` and `strValue1 = Evaluate("--" & sht.Range("B" & i).Address(1,1,,1))` then add them.

Comment: I don't think you have to evaluate them cause the `.Value2` field has the values already. Just simple addition but you have reference that field of the range.

Comment: @nbayly It appears that the dates are text that looks like dates not numbers formatted as dates.  So Value2 will just return the string and the addition will not be possible.

Comment: @shilohln can you confirm if the values you have saved are stored as a string or as date/time as per Scott's suspicion?

Comment: Scott is correct, the dates are only text.  I have imported this data from a csv and it imports in as general format.  Because of formatting in the csv, however, the times are text as well because of the lack of zero padding until 10:00:00.  At that time they import in as custom format and excel recognizes it as a time.  Trying some of these solutions now.

Comment: @Dan, I just tried that.  Error 438, Object doesn't support that method.

Comment: @ScottCraner I will update my original post with all of my code up to this point.  Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the dates and times are strings so something like this will work:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
   strValue = Evaluate("VALUE(TRIM(" & sht.Range("A" & i).Address(1,1,,1) & "))")
   strValue1 = Evaluate("VALUE(TRIM(" & sht.Range("B" & i).Address(1,1,,1) & "))")
   sht.Range("C" & i).Value = strValue + strValue1
   'the format
   sht.Range("C" & i).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss"
Next i
```

Comment: Your suspicion was correct for the most part.  They are text, but when I run that code I get a type mismatch error right off the bat at the first row of data.

Comment: Yeah, used this exact code.  I get a type mismatch immediately on the For loop.

Comment: On the actual for statement or the first variable line?

Comment: First variable line (second really).  The top row (which is always blank) gets the properly formatted date in the C column (1900-01-00 00:00:00 since A1 and B1 are blank).  Get the error once it hits row 2.

Comment: I wonder if you have extra spaces either before or after the date.  Does the Value() function on the worksheet work without VBA?

Comment: Oh!  Never noticed that.  Yes, there is one extra space before both the date and time.  And yes, the Value() function works well.  I'm just trying to automate this stuff because there are hundreds of files to do this to.

Comment: Still getting a type mismatch.  Doesn't do the blank row now either.  Thanks so much for the help, sorry this is a PITA probelm.

Comment: Start at row 2 not 1.

Comment: YES!  It works!  Thank you very much!  I totally missed that i=2 part.  Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference the `.Value2` field of the range element as:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
   sht.Range("C" & i).Value2 = sht.Range("A" & i).Value2 + sht.Range("B" & i).Value2
Next i
```

The value is free of formatting and just in Excel's time/date code as you want your final result to be. Cheers,

Comment: Unfortunately, this ends up working the same as just using .Value.  Just concatenates the face value of the cells and pastes that in.  Also I am getting a type mismatch error once the B column hits 10:00:00 for the reasons mentioned in my above comment.